# How can I preserve parentheses enclosing a dot product in a HoldForm[]?

Tags: output-formatting, formatting, hold

I am having a problem with keeping the parentheses enclosing a dot product in `HoldForm[]`. I want to keep them in my equations since they indicate important grouping information. To prevent MMA removing the parentheses, I placed the whole expression in a `HoldForm[]`, but MMA ignored that and still deleted them, which annoyed me quite a lot.

Example 1:
The expression I was trying to input and what I got:

[image]

```
HoldForm[(a . b) (c . d) == 
  Subscript[a, j] Subscript[b, j] Subscript[c, k] Subscript[d, k]]
```

[image]

Example 2:
The expression I was trying to input and what I got:

[image]

```
HoldForm[u + (a . b) v == a . a (b . v) a]
```

[image]

Example 3:
The expression I was trying to input and what I got:

[image]

```
HoldForm[a\[Cross](b\[Cross]c) == (a . c) b - (a . b) c]
```

[image]

So I was wondering, how can I make MMA preserve the parentheses around a certain expression like dot product I placed in `HoldForm[]`?

Comment: Have you seen [`PrecedenceForm`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PrecedenceForm.html)?

Comment: Thanks @LukasLang. I had never heard of it until saw your suggestion. I read the documentation just now and found it useful. However, there seems no method or function to find the precedence levels specified by integers of a certain operation, despite few of the them are listed in the notes for `Infix`. If there is a way to find integer-specified precedence levels for any operator, then solution you suggested would be perfect enough.

Comment: You can use the (undocumented for some reason) function `Precedence` to get the numbers, e.g. `Precedence[Times]` gives `400`.

Comment: Posting code is nicer than posting images.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelE2 for your suggestion. I have made an addendum of code to my original post. Hope it looks nicer now.

Comment: Thanks for including it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<sub>*Putting my comment into an answer*</sub>

You can use [`PrecedenceForm`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PrecedenceForm.html) to get what you want:

```
HoldForm[PrecedenceForm[a.b, 350] PrecedenceForm[c.d, 350] == 
  Subscript[a,i] Subscript[b,i] Subscript[c,k] Subscript[d,k]]
```

[image]

The precedence of `350` just needs to be lower than the precedence of `Times` (so that `a.b` needs parentheses, similar to how `a+b` would need paretheses since its precedence is lower than that of `Times`). To get the precedence, `Precedence` (undocumented) can be used:

```
Precedence[Times]
(* 400. *)
```

Comment: Thanks Lukas! No wonder I did not find the method to get the precedence integers, as you said it turns out to be undocumented. Since that can be obtained through`Precedence[]`, the solution you suggested is perfect enough! I have accepted it !